# Mapping where clause generic type (of SelectConditionStep) to my own class in jooq

Tags: java, jooq

So I have an abstract class that prepares my query up to after where clause. It looks something like this:

```java
SelectConditionStep<Record2<Integer, String>> whereQuery = dslContext.select(FOO.DIGITS, FOO.WORD)
                                                                .from(FOO)
                                                                .where(/*some conditions*/);
```

It then returns `whereQuery` and that instance is used by concrete implementations to add stuff onto it.

Is it possible to make this call return `SelectConditionStep<MyClass>` so that I don't have to write all Record types in method signature (note that this is a simplified version, imagine having Record10). `MyClass` would, in this example, have two fields, `Integer` and `String` fields.
Or if not that, is there any other way to do it.

I am using Postgres as a db

Comment: While I can answer your *specific* question, there's likely a better solution to this. If you're interested, just ask a new question with your *actual* question (i.e. what kind of dynamic SQL you're trying to achieve here).

Comment: Hey, sorry for not responding sooner, I was looking just for this mapping below, that was in fact my real question. I wouldn't call this query a dynamic query, it is just that we are reusing part of the query for 2 tables that are similar in structure and purpose, but still different, and also are not part of same database so it is more of the way we have organized our code

Comment: OK, all the better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an immutable POJO `MyClass`, e.g. a Java 16 record:

```java
record MyClass(int digits, String word) {}
```

You could use a nested record to achieve something similar:

```java
Select<Record1<MyClass>> whereQuery =
ctx.select(row(FOO.DIGITS, FOO.WORD).mapping(MyClass::new))
   .from(FOO)
   .where(...)
```