# Reuse RecordMapper in a jOOQ multiset query

Tags: java, jooq

Let's say we have a table `car` and `parts`. To fetch all car with their parts we use the following query:

```java
@Transactional
public List<ReadCarDto> getAllCars() {
    return getDslContext().select(
        CAR.ID,
        CAR.NAME,
        CAR.DESCRIPTION,
        multiset(
            selectDistinct(
                PARTS.ID,
                PARTS.NAME,
                PARTS.TYPE,
                PARTS.DESCRIPTION
            ).from(PARTS).where(PARTS.CAR_ID.eq(CAR.ID))
        ).convertFrom(record -> record.map(record1 -> new ReadPartDto(
            record1.value1(),
            record1.value2(),
            record1.value3(),
            record1.value4()
        )))
    ).from(CAR).fetch(record -> new ReadCarDto(
        record.value1(),
        record.value2(),
        record.value3(),
        record.value4()
    ));
}
```

**Question**: I always want to fetch the full car and part rows. Is there a way to reuse my existing `private RecordMapper<CarRecord, ReadCarDto> getCarMapper()` method that already implements the DTO conversion (For parts too of course)? Otherwise I have to retype the conversion in my multiset queries.

It looks like the `selectDistinct` method only has support for 1 - 22 fields and `select().from(CAR)` doesn't provide a `multiset` method.

Sidenote: I don't want to use the reflection conversion.

Answer (score 0):

[Your question reminds me of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71049951/521799). You probably want to use a [`nested row() expression to produce nested records`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/). Something like this:

```java
return getDslContext()
    .select(
        row(
            CAR.ID,
            CAR.NAME,
            CAR.DESCRIPTION,
            ...
        ).mapping(carMapper),
        multiset(...)
    )
```

A future jOOQ version will let you use `CAR` directly as a nested row in your projections, see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4727. As of jOOQ 3.16, this isn't available yet.